# Block dispatch_queue until it sends the entire data

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, tcp, gcdasyncsocket

I am trying to send some hexadecimal packets that create a waveform at the server side in objective c by creating a tcp/ip connection.My problem is that i am able to send the data and can also see the waveform at the server side.But what happens is that due to network delays sometimes the waveform seens to be overlapped(the reason is the server tries to sync the packets every after 5 minutes). My question here is basically how to send the packets to the server in such a way that until the packets are synced i dont send another packket to the server

```
    dispatch_queue_t connectionTest=dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
                    dispatch_async(connectionTest, ^{
                    if(outputStream)
                    {

                        NSInteger sizeOfPacket=13;
                        unsigned char myPacket[13];
                        unsigned char crcCal=0;
                        myPacket[0]=START_OF_HEADER;
                        myPacket[1]=START_OF_TEXT;
                        myPacket[2]=8;
                        myPacket[3]=0x6a;
                        myPacket[4]=0x06;
                        myPacket[5]=0x80;
                        myPacket[6]=Some value;// 
                        myPacket[7]=0x80;
                        myPacket[8]=Some value;//
                        myPacket[9]=0x54;//changed 54 to 50
                        myPacket[10]=0x04;
                        for (int j=3;j<myPacket[2]+3;j++)
                        {
                            crcCal=crcTable[crcCal^myPacket[j]];
                        }
                        myPacket[11]=crcCal;
                        myPacket[12]=END_OF_TEXT;

                        NSLog(@"crc value is %c",crcCal);


                        NSData* dataPacket = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)myPacket length:sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeOfPacket];
                        [outputStream write:[dataPacket bytes] maxLength:[dataPacket length]];

                    }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to `dispatch_suspend` the outgoing queue from within the block where you send a packet, and then `dispatch_resume` the outgoing queue from whatever code receives the acknowledgment from the server.